# Which Constraints Should I Compare with First in Quadratic Optimization Problem?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, newton-raphson, quadratic-programming

I trying to minimize this objective function.

$$J(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^THx + c^Tx$$

First I thought I could use Newtown's Method, but later I found Gradient Descent, which is more suitable for this type of problem.

I first turn $J(x)$ into the deritivate.

$$\Delta J(x) = x^TH + c^T$$

And I want to find $x$ when $\Delta J(x)$ is small as possible. I could use gradient descent for that.

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \gamma \Delta J(x_n)$$

In this example, I set the constraints limits $LB$ for lower bound and $UB$ for upper bound.

```
% We want to solve Ax=b with constraints (bounds)
A = [3 2; -6 5];
b = [4; 6];
x = linsolve(A, b) % Unconstrained 

% Create a quadratic forumla
H = A'*A;
c = A'*b;
% Create the derivative
dJdx = @(x) (x'*H + c')';

LB = [0.1;0.5]; % Lower bounds for x
UB = [1.0;1.4]; % Upper bounds for x
y = 0.001; % Learning rate
x = [1;1]; % Initial state
for i = 1:3000
  % Compute the next state
  x = x - y*dJdx(x);

  % Constraints
  for j = 1:length(A)
    % On x
    if(-x(j) > UB(j))
        x(j) = -UB(j);
    elseif(-x(j) < LB(j))
        x(j) = -LB(j);
    endif
  endfor

endfor
x = -x % This needs
```

But what if I want to have the constraints

$$LB <= x <= UB$$
$$LBA <= Ax <= UBA$$

If I first compare the $x$ constraints, then the $Ax$ constraints might not fit? Or is it a way to determine of these constraints cannot work with each other first?

Example, if I extend the Octave code.

```
% We want to solve Ax=b with constraints (bounds)
A = [3 2; -6 5];
b = [4; 6];
x = linsolve(A, b) % Unconstrained 

% Create a quadratic forumla
H = A'*A;
c = A'*b;
% Create the derivative
dJdx = @(x) (x'*H + c')';

LB = [0.1;0.5]; % Lower bounds for x
UB = [1.0;1.4]; % Upper bounds for x
LBA = [1; 1]; % Lower bounds for Ax
UBA = [4; 5]; % Upper bounds for Ax

y = 0.001; % Learning rate
x = [1;1]; % Initial state
for i = 1:3000
  % Compute the next state
  x = x - y*dJdx(x);

  % Constraints
  for j = 1:length(A)

    % For upper bound
    if(-(A*x)(j) > UBA(j) && -x(j) > UB(j))
        % What to write here?
    elseif(-(A*x)(j) < UBA(j) && -x(j) < UB(j))
        % No nothing here - Everything is normal
    elseif(-(A*x)(j) < UBA(j) && -x(j) > UB(j))
        x(j) = -UB(j);
    elseif(-(A*x)(j) > UBA(j) && -x(j) < UB(j))
        % What to write here?
    endif

    % For lower bound
    if(-(A*x)(j) > LBA(j) && -x(j) > LB(j))
        % No nothing here - Everything is normal
    elseif(-(A*x)(j) < LBA(j) && -x(j) < LB(j))
        % What to write here?
    elseif(-(A*x)(j) < LBA(j) && -x(j) > LB(j))
        % What to write here?
    elseif(-(A*x)(j) > LBA(j) && -x(j) < LB(j))
        x(j) = -LB(j);
    endif


  endfor

endfor
x = -x % This needs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the following

$$C_1 = \{x : LB <= x <= UB\}\,,$$
$$C_2 = \{x : LBA <= Ax <= UBA\}\,.$$

Note that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed convex sets. So, your problem becomes the following

$$\min_{x \in C_1\cap C_2} J(x)\,,$$

where $C_1\cap C_2$ is a closed convex set. The problem can be equivalently written as

$$\min_{x \in R^N} J(x) + I_{C_1\cap C_2}\,.$$

Now, you may use the Projected Gradient Descent, which is a special case of Forward-Backward Splitting.

The update step essentially involves

$$x_{n+1} = P_{C_1\cap C_2}(x_n - \gamma_n \nabla J(x_n))\,.$$

But, obtaining closed form in general is difficult, so to solve the subproblem you may use

1. Projections onto convex sets (POCS, a.k.a Alternating projections)
2. or Dykstra's projection algorithm
3. or Douglas Rachford
4. or ADMM.

Reference: [Patrick L. Combettes, Jean-Christophe Pesquet - Proximal Splitting Methods in Signal Processing](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3522).

Comment: Thank you very much...but I can't read that type of math (I'm more applied), so I prefer instead if-statements and for-loops. But thanks for the info :)

Comment: Essentially you need to project onto to the intersection of two sets. So, first you need to figure out how to project onto $C_1\cap C_2$, which can be difficult. You can easily calculate the projection on each of the sets seperately and use POCS if possible. But, the math is heavy probably.  Someone downvoted it, not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think that might be to difficult for me. I'm only going to solve a Ax=b problem with simple constraints. Can't I use if-statement and for-loops instead? That might works?

Comment: It might work, but then again it depends on luck. POCS will converge to intersection if the intersection is non-empty. POCS is described in quite some detail here at https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/alt_proj.pdf. Dykstra's projection algorithm is even better as it will converge to the point which is at short distance to intersection.  I can update the answer tomorrow with the code. I recommend strongly reading about POCS to get an idea.

Comment: Thank you. That would be very nice. I'm not a math expert. Cannot read this type of math because I feel that the explanations have lack of pedagogy.

Comment: I updated my question. Se code below.

Comment: Will python code work for you?

Comment: Do you have MATLAB? Or GNU Octave?

Comment: I do not have it.

Comment: Ok. Python works as well. GNU Octave is free by the way.

Comment: I am comfortable with Python. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: It appears to me that the intersection of the constraints is an empty set. Did you check it already?

Comment: Check the constraints? I don't even know yet how they are. All I know is that they are on that form above.

Comment: They are just halfspaces. I will check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101284/discussion-between-mahesh-and-daniel-martensson).