# Solve Matrix Linear Least Squares with Frobenius Norm Regularization and Linear Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

How to solve the following constrained minimization problem:
$$
\arg_S min_\; \frac{1}{2}\left \{ \left \| K_2SK_1^T-M \right \|_F^2 +\lambda \left \| S \right \|_F^2\right \} \\
s.t. \sum_{1}^{col}S=Sum1 \\
\sum_{1}^{row}S=Sum2 \\
$$
where $K_1$,$K_2$,$M$ and $S$ are 2d Matrix, and only $S$ is unknown. In the constraints, $Sum1$ is the sum along the column of $S$, which is a row vector. $Sum2$ is the sum along the row of $S$, which is a column vector.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kfvaru3m5ytNj72DA865wG5KoIdX3iPP/view?usp=sharing) is the data stored in mat format. How to solve this kind of problem?

```
    load('matlab.mat');
%　 min norm( K2*X*K1'-M,'fro')^2+lambda*norm(X,'fro')^2
%   s.t. sum(X,1) = Sum1 ;   sum(X,2) = Sum2;
```

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to bring the problem into the form:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{ \boldsymbol{s} } \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| K \boldsymbol{s} - \boldsymbol{m} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{s} \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & A \boldsymbol{s} = \boldsymbol{u} \\
\quad & B \boldsymbol{s} = \boldsymbol{v}
\end{aligned}$$

Using the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) we can see that:

- $ K = {K}_{1} \otimes {K}_{2} $.
- $ \boldsymbol{s} = \operatorname{vec} \left( S \right) $ where $ \operatorname{vec} \left( \cdot \right) $ is the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).
- $ \boldsymbol{m} = \operatorname{vec} \left( M \right) $.

The matrices $ A $ and $ B $ are just **Selectors** of the corresponding elements in $ \boldsymbol{s} $.

**Remark**
Pay attention that if $ A $ and $ B $ represent a matrix which selects each element of $ \boldsymbol{s} $ **exactly once** then $ \sum_{i} {u}_{i} = \sum_{i} {v}_{i} $ must hold as it represent the sum of $ \boldsymbol{s} $. Namely $ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} A \boldsymbol{s} = \boldsymbol{1}^{T} B \boldsymbol{s} = \sum_{i} {s}_{i} $. This is the case for your constraints. So it must be like that in order to have a feasible solution.

Now the above is a basic Convex problem which can be solved by Projected Gradient Descent where we project onto the [intersection of the 2 equality constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095).

You could even do something simpler by concatenate the matrices and vectors:

$$ C \boldsymbol{s} = \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{s} = \boldsymbol{w} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{u} \\ \boldsymbol{v} \end{bmatrix} $$

Then it is very similar to [Linear Least Squares with Equality Constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596362).

An interesting resource with that regard is [Robert M. Freund - Projection Methods for Linear Equality Constrained Problems](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-084j-nonlinear-programming-spring-2004/lecture-notes/lec9_project_mthd.pdf).

Comment: The explanation and the links helped me a lot. One more question:
Is it possible to include a non-negative constraint for the elements of $S$? If yes, how to solve this kind of problems which have both equality and inequality constraints?
I can solve it with CVX. But I'm curious about how to solve it without using any out-of-box tools.

Comment: @Shannon, Open a new question with this additional constraint and I will try to answer it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957019/solve-tikhonov-regularization-problem-with-linear-equality-constraints-and-non-n
 could you please give me a runnable matlab script? I‘ve forked your git repo.

Comment: any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I hope to have time to work this on weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using MATLAB, so it's easy to use CVX.

```
cvx_begin
variable S(size(K2,2),size(K1,2))
minimize(0.5*(square_pos(norm(K2*S*K1'-M,'fro'))+lambda*square_pos(norm(S,'fro'))))
sum(S,1) == Sum1
sum(S,2) == Sum2
cvx_end
```

Comment: are there any additional settings? I cannot get a solution use CVX. It returns
Status: Infeasible
Optimal value (cvx_optval): +Inf

Comment: I've tried to change the solver & control the precisions. Still cannot get a appropriate solution. Idk where is the problem.

Comment: Presumably, your Sum1 and SUm2 are incompatible, i.e., there's no matrix which satisfy both the row and column sum constraints. That would be the case if $sum(Sum1) \ne sum(Sum2)$

Comment: Sum1 and Sum2 are compatible because this is a synthetic data.

Comment: Then you;d have to show a reproducible example demonstrating what you say. You can do that at http://ask.cvxr.com/ .

Comment: http://ask.cvxr.com/t/cannot-get-a-result/8178