# Solve Least Squares with Tikhonov Regularization Linear Equality and Non Negative Constrains

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, least-squares

How to solve the following constrained minimization problem:
$$
\arg_S min_\; \frac{1}{2}\left \{ \left \| K_2SK_1^T-M \right \|_F^2 +\lambda \left \| S \right \|_F^2\right \} \\
s.t. \sum_{1}^{col}S=Sum1 \\
\sum_{1}^{row}S=Sum2 \\
s_{i,j} \in S \geq 0 \\
$$

where $K_1$,$K_2$,$M$ and $S$ are 2d Matrix, and only $S$ is unknown. In the constraints, $Sum1$ is the sum along the column of $S$, which is a row vector. $Sum2$ is the sum along the row of $S$, which is a column vector.  All elements in $S$ are non-negative.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kfvaru3m5ytNj72DA865wG5KoIdX3iPP/view?usp=sharing) is the data stored in mat format. How to solve this kind of problem? Are there any MATLAB routines I can use out-of-box?

```
    load('matlab.mat');
%　 min norm( K2*X*K1'-M,'fro')^2+lambda*norm(X,'fro')^2
%   s.t. sum(X,1) = Sum1 ;   sum(X,2) = Sum2; all(X>=0) = true
```

**What I've Tried:**

- CVX:

Failed to find the optimal solution with all supported solvers. Here is the cvx script I use:

```
cvx_begin
variable S(size(K2,2),size(K1,2))
minimize(0.5*(square_pos(norm(K2*S*K1'-M,'fro'))+lambda*square_pos(norm(S,'fro'))))
sum(S,1) == Sum1
sum(S,2) == Sum2
S>=0
cvx_end
```

**Edit:**

A synthetic data with much smaller scale was attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qkHq9rBcLPPLNYp0f-UpBPpo7zE5QCQ7/view?usp=sharing). DR was also normalized.

Comment: Please produce smaller data example and I will be able to publish code. Also make sure the dynamic range of the problem is reduced (As you were guided in http://ask.cvxr.com/t/8178).

Comment: @Shanon, The matrix `M` is missing in the data you linked. Moreover, the DR is still huge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective Function is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{S} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| {K}_{2} S {K}_{1}^{T} - M \right\|}_{F}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| S \right\|}_{F}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {S}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} = \boldsymbol{u} \\
& S \boldsymbol{1} = \boldsymbol{v} \\
& S \geq 0
\end{aligned}$$

While one could use many specialized solvers for the above problem I'd start with the Projected Gradient Descent.
In order to use the Projected Gradient Descent we need the projection onto the intersection of all 3 constraints sets.
Yet, since the set $ \left\{ S \mid S \geq 0 \right\} $ isn't a sub space we can't use the alternating projection method (See [Projections onto Convex Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets) and [Projection of $ z $ onto the Affine Half Space $ \left\{ x \mid A x = b, \; x \geq 0 \right\} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537129)).
It can be solved using the [Dykstra's Projection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm) from [Orthogonal Projection onto the Intersection of Convex Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095).
The [Dykstra's Projection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm) requires the projection onto each set to generate an iterative algorithm to computer the projection onto the intersection of all sets.

Hence, the *atoms* of the projected gradient Descent are:

1. The Gradient of the objective function: $ {K}_{2}^{T} \left( {K}_{2} S {K}_{1}^{T} - M \right) {K}_{1} + \lambda S  $.
2. Projection onto the 1st constraint: $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ X \mid {X}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} = \boldsymbol{u} \right\} } \left( Y \right) = Y - \boldsymbol{1} \frac{ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} Y - \boldsymbol{u}^{T} }{ 
   \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} } $.
3. Projection onto the 2nd constraint: $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ X \mid X \boldsymbol{1} = \boldsymbol{v} \right\} } \left( Y \right) = Y - \frac{ Y \boldsymbol{1} - \boldsymbol{v} }{ 
   \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} } \boldsymbol{1}^{T} $.
4. Projection onto the 3rd constraint: $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \left\{ X \mid X \geq 0 \right\} } \left( Y \right) = \max \left( Y, 0 \right) $.

**Remark**: Since $ \boldsymbol{1} $ is a vector of ones (With the appropriate dimension in each use above) the projections steps could be optimized. For example $ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} = m $ or $ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} = n $ (Number of rows / columns) and using `sum()` and `repamt()` to imitate the multiplication by the vector.

I implemented the solution in MATLAB and got the following results compared to CVX:

[image]

The iterative methods are slower than `CVX` for this task (I used `MOSEK`).
Yet, this is on small size of the data. Probably they will be able to be faster for large scale problem (Still you'll have to give a solver a lot of time to get the result).

I'd also recommend adding Line Search. As this problem is not well poised.

Comment: I'v edited my post.

Comment: Does it include the M matrix?

Comment: Yep. And the synthetic 'solution' was also included. "S_synthetic" in the mat file.

Comment: I've read all links you provide but I still didn't know where the project operators come from. Could you pls give me more details about that two operators?

Comment: You may have a look at [Orthogonal Projection of $ z $ onto the Affine set $ \left\{ x \mid A x = b \right\} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320363).

Comment: The matlab function works well for most of my data. But for some data(e.g. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kun8Y8_rjA8SJO_weREc_lSzS_MHCdtT/view?usp=sharing), it could never converge to a reasonable solution. I've struggled to solve it servaral weeks. Could you please give me some advises / suggestions /explannations about why this kind of data cannot converge?

Comment: I get `sum(vV) == sum(vU)` to be `false` on your data.

Comment: `abs(sum(vV)-sum(vU) < eps`

Comment: I‘ve checked the data stored in UserData1.mat  and I get `sum(vV)==sum(vU)` to be `true`.